# How to compare two values of two different child in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display the data based on the scheduled date saved on the database, i tried comparing it to the current date of the device, but it didn't work. This is my saved data from firebase:

[image: My data from firebase]

This is the Logcat
[image: Logcat]

**This is the Adapter class:**

```
 public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    
        Context context;
    
        ArrayList<Reminder> list;
    
    
        public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Reminder> list) {
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(v);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    
            Reminder Reminder = list.get(position);
            holder.t.setText(Reminder.gett());
            holder.d.setText(Reminder.getd());
            holder.tm.setText(Reminder.gettm());
            holder.dt.setText(Reminder.getdt());
            holder.currentDate.setText(Reminder.getcurrentDate());
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }
    
        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
            TextView t, d, tm, dt, currentDate;
    
            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
    
                t = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
                d = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);
                tm = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvtime);
                dt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
                currentDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvcdate);
    
    
            }
        }
    
    }
```

**This is my code to retrieve the data from the database:**

```
 public class ReminderMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference database;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentdate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
com.example.luntian.adapter.ListAdapter ListAdapter;
ArrayList<Reminder> list;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userList);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Reminder");
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    list = new ArrayList<Reminder>();
    ListAdapter = new ListAdapter(this,list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(ListAdapter);

    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Reminder reminder = dataSnapshot.getValue(Reminder.class);
                    list.add(reminder);


                }
                ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? Besides that, please edit your question and add the content of your `Reminder` class.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag. That also has the added advantage that it enabled syntax highlighting on the code in your question.

Comment: The errors Alex mentioned are in `onCancelled`, which Firebase uses to signal problems with your listener, but which your code ignores. A simple `onCancelled` could look like this: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. --- Please make this change to your code and try it again. After that, edit your question (there's a link right under it for this purpose) to show us the updated code, and explain what isn't working about it.